# DART: Communitacation beetween Threads

Tags: multithreading, dart, publish-subscribe, channel, pubnub

I'm trying to create a Dart program that will invoke multiple threads or Isolates. I need communication between this threads or Isolates, I have seen that there are some kind of channels and isolated channels (channels that work with ReceivePorts) but I need somethings that works similar to PubSub pattern, a Thread or Isolate will send a object (I need it to be a object, I know there is PubNub with Strings) and the rest of Threads or Isolates receives it.

Do you know something that could do the work? It would be great it there are some examples, I am relatively new with Dart language.

Answer (score 0):

> I know there is PubNub with Strings

Does it mean, [Publishing](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/dart/api-reference/publish-and-subscribe#publishing-jsonobject-google-gson) only strings through PubNub? - It's not limited to strings. If that is stopper then custom objects can be published through pubnub dart sdk.